# In MVC passing a list from JSP to the Controller

Tags: spring, jsp, model-view-controller, jstl

I'm trying to get an example of passing a list from JSP to the Controller to work:

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-mvc-multi-row-submit-java-list/

the problem I have with this example is that I do not get the JSP /WebContent/WEB-INF/jsp/add_contact.jsp to work. He has the line:

```
<c:foreach items="${contactForm.contacts}" var="contact" varstatus="status">
```

and i'm getting errors with the **varstatus** variable. From where is he getting the values for this variable? He is using it as a list row index, but from where should the values come? I get the warning in eclipse that it is a not defined variable varstatus and if i still deploy it to tomcat, then i get the error that jstl foreach tag does not support more than one variable (as i already have the contact there).

Comment: Instead of doing this much code you can pass single contactForm object directly to controller and get contacts from it.

Comment: Harshal Patil, thank you for your comment, but if you think about it, then your comment does not help me at all (1. you do not answer my questions 2. you say there are better alternatives, but you do not say which ones).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`forEach`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/forEach.html) tag and attributes are case sensitive.

```
<c:forEach items="${contactForm.contacts}" var="contact" varStatus="status">
    <c:out value="${status.index}" />: <c:out value="${contact}" />
</c:forEach>
```

It's possible the error messages generated by Eclipse are misleading. It's also possible the error is originating from somewhere else on the page. If this does not resolve the problem, post the full JSP and stacktrace for better understanding.